# Copy paste from another workbook on opening - Then use for data validation

Tags: excel, vba

I'm wondering if I am going about setting this up the right way.

I have a workbook which has the equipment we use and the hourly cost. This is the most up-to-date document.

I am creating a new workbook and I am trying to reference the information in the equipment workbook in my new workbook.

Originally my thought was to copy the information needed over, triggered by opening up the new workbook.

```
Workbooks("Equipment Costs Current Year RESTRICTED.xlsm").Worksheets("T&M Sheet Import").Range("f:g").Copy
activeWB.Worksheets("Equipment").Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

Then I had it set to convert to a table

```
Dim tbOb As ListObject
    Dim TblRng As Range
     With Sheets("equipment")
        lLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        lLastColumn = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        Set TblRng = .Range("A1", .Cells(lLastRow, lLastColumn))
        Set tbOb = .ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, TblRng, , xlYes)
        tbOb.Name = "EquipmentTable1"
        tbOb.TableStyle = "TableStyleMedium14"
    End With
```

I am using Name Manager and used this:

```
=OFFSET(Equipment!A$1,0,0,COUNTA(Equipment!A:A)-1)
```

Finally, the goal here is that I am trying to use data validation for a drop down menu in my RFCO workbook to show currently available equipment, and then a vlookup to fill in relevant boxes with current cost/mark up etc.

I am running into so many problems that I am not even sure where I went wrong:

- sometimes the data seems to paste and other times it says subscript out of range
- In my data validation drop down I have 100s of blanks at the bottom

Comment: If you are pasting values, just set ranges to each other. Going to need more code to help better.

Comment: You're pasting to "Equipment" but the table is on "Labor Rates" ?

Comment: Sorry to confuse. I am actually pulling both equipment and labor rates into two different sheets. Didn't mean to copy paste one of each here. It is correct in the workbook and I'll edit.

Comment: Fixed the title so you are not SHOUTING at us. It now matches the other question titles.

Comment: Can you add the full code?

Comment: @TimWilliams thanks for the correction; i was thinking that was written as "A1,B2,C3" when i saw the use of "A1" inside... removing earlier comment.

Comment: Using a listobject as the source for a data validation list:  https://exceloffthegrid.com/using-an-excel-table-within-a-data-validation-list/#INDIRECT_Function

Comment: thanks @TimWilliams you are always so helpful!!

Answer (score 0):

I just tried adding a line where the current table is deleted at the beginning and that seems to have solved the first part of the problem!

```
Worksheets("Equipment").ListObjects("EquipmentTable1").Delete
```